# Dotnet build on Ubuntu returns code 1

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 solution that compiles fine in a Windows environment. When I attempt to build it in an Ubuntu environment, it appears to have compiled successfully:

> 267 Warning(s)
>
> 0 Error(s)

but it returns an exit code of 1 (should be 0). I dug back through the logs and found:

> Build FAILED.

but there are no errors anywhere in the output, and no clue as to why the build failed!

How do I diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I diagnose this problem?

Add the `-bl` argument to generate a  `msbuild.binlog` (or use `-bl:/path/to/build.binlog`) file which you can later analyze using the [MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com) to look at the failure source and try to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't answer the question directly (how to diagnose), but I did manage to diagnose the problem anyway.

`dotnet build` by default creates artifacts for the *Windows* environment. If you want a build to work in Linux, you have to specify that in the command line arguments, e.g.

```
dotnet build -r linux-x64
```

So while compilation was working fine, it couldn't create any Linux compatible binaries!

D'oh!

Comment: "dotnet build by default creates artifacts for the Windows environment." doesn't sound right at all. I suspect one of your project files is explicitly setting up a Windows runtime id, overriding the default of linux-x64 on linux.